# There is no STM32 chip through the USB driver WIFI module program？

Tags: stm32

I want to make a network camera, stm32 through the camera to collect images, and then sent to the server through the WIFI module. As 1 second need to transfer a lot of data, so I would like to use the USB interface wifi module program to achieve. Or what better solution to achieve.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have no idea how the USB works.

You have a couple solutions.

1. Use a wifi module with SPI interface.
2. Use a SOC like CC3200.L
3. Use ESPxxxx module or similar (RTL8710)

You can of course try to use STM with host usb interface, but you will have to implement the USB host stack + driver for USB wifi module + network stack (eg TCP/IP stack). But it is quite complicated as the STM ones are not very good, there are some better paid ones - but expensive. USB host is not easy to implement.

Comment: In fact, I prefer to use the SOC, the camera directly to the pictures sent to the server, without having to go through other chip data exchange. Actually what I have to do is something like a wireless camera, so I'm upset about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go along the "networking over USB" path on STM32 (and I'm assuming you're not planning to buy any commercial drivers) it's going to be rough for you.

When it comes to USB, vast majority of the WiFi dongle drivers are proprietary and unless you're on an operating system such as Windows or Linux you're out of luck, unless you want to for the reverse engineering or porting at least parts of the drivers from Linux. With the USB you can think of using the USB-ECM (ethernet over USB) class, but two things here. One - ST doesn't provide any free implementations of this class so you're down do searching for it or implementing it yourself. After a bit of googling I've found one instance of this on githbu, although I havent tested it myself. Second thing - this is no longer wireless as you'll need to be connected to some kind of host providing internet connection, at which point it's probably better to not use USB-ECM and networking at all and just send data using a class that can be implemented easily (USB-CDC or USB-HID). I'm a bit worried about the throughput here.

You can also try to find WiFi modules that are connected over other interface. Generally those modules are connected over UART, some over SPI. This way, integrating it with the TCP/IP stack will also be up to you, at least when it comes to implementing the WiFi module protocol (most likely AT-commands) and implementing network interface so that the stack can "talk" to it. In this approach, I'm almost sure that you'll lack the throughput required for your application.

Personally I'd strongly suggest trying Ethernet if that's an option for you. It's going to be highest bandwidth (which you're going to need), plus it's most "out of the box". There's multiple projects implementing various applications using a free LWIP stack over this interface, including examples generated by ST's CubeMX.

Comment: It's quite unclear what he's asking about as he didn't specify whether using USB interface is a must, or the device being wireless, or he just needs to "send a lot of data" to the server and he thought of WiFi modules connected over USB as being the easiest to implement, as they're "plug and play" on PCs. One could argue in your answer as well that "he asked about USB wifi modules and you gave him non-USB solutions", but that's not the point. I showed him what are pros and cons of each approach and how much work it would take to impement each.

Comment: It is clear, he is only worried about fast enough transmission.

Comment: Thank you for your answer！
For some reason, I had to choose the wireless transmission method to transfer data. The reason to choose to use USB with USB interface WIFI module, because I need to send 30 photos in 1 second to the server, if the use of UART, SPI interface, WIFI module, and STM32 data transmission between the requirements can not be achieved, so I only consider whether to use a USB interface with the WIFI module will be better.